# Color scheme for iPhone app

Tags: iphone

It has been suggested to me to have unified color scheme for my iPhone app. They said the colors in my app are incoherent and clash.

What tools are there to help with this and where can I find examples?

Comment: Find the color attributes of stuff, maybe? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Not color attributes. Being able to pick colors which go together for the buttons, menus, background etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at some colour theory

As a short cut there are some useful online tools you can find to help you find colour schemes that aren't too offensive :-)

You may find some of the links under http://www.delicious.com/adrianh/colour of use.

Cheers,

Adrian

Answer (score 1):

This is not something that you can really do with tools. It's about aesthetics, consistency and good UI design. I' suggest doing some reading on UI design and the way people perceive colour and it's effect. I.e. find out why red is usually used for errors and warnings. Understand where and when you should use muted or strong colour. Understand what makes a good interface and what doesn't.

These things are not specific to iPhones, they are relevant to any UI design for any system or hardware.